# How to catch StreamNotFound on a LIVE NetStream?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, streaming, flash-media-server

I have an FLEX application where I need to know if the LIVE stream on FMS exists when I do a NetStream.play();
Example:

```
var stream = new NetStream(nc);
stream.play("streamnotexists");
```

How can I pick the error on play how are trying to play a tream that not exists ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a listener function on your netstream, for status type event. As a status you get **NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound** .
Refer to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html) and [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000185.html) for further understanding.

Answer (score -1):

You should add a listener to your NetStream object, like so:

```
stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
```

where `netStatusHandler` is:

```
function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch (event.info.code) {
                // some other cases
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                    trace("Unable to locate vod stream: " + videoURL);
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify":
                    trace("Unable to locate live stream: "+ videoURL);
                // rest of the cases, default, etc
            }
        }
```

The complete list of event.info.code can be found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html but be aware that only the events that begin in `NetStream.` are triggered by the NetStream object.

Comment: You're right, but instead NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify should be triggered. I've updated the code.

Comment: So, any updates? Did it work, eventually, with UnpublishNotify?

Comment: I don't get a `NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify` status code, this didn't work for me.

Comment: It may depend on the media server you're using, as the media server is the one that sends that event.